# Add dynamic type into Entity Framework Context

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a method that will create a dynamic type using:
    Activator.CreateInstance(myType)

but I am having trouble how to add to the entity framework context and do SaveChanges as I do not know which DbSet it is.

Is there anyway to dynamically add the objects to the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the type which is mapped in your context you can try to use this:

```
context.Set(myType).Add(createdInstance);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem and this solution works as a charm!